# jQuery add and remove class checking

Tags: javascript, jquery

This function works. No issues with it working.

```js
if ($(".register-frame").length) {
    var emailCheck = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/
    $('#email-field').change(function () {
        if (!$('#email-field').val().match(emailCheck)) {
            if ($("#email-field").hasClass("field-success")) {
                $("#email-field").removeClass('field-success');
            }
            if (!$("#email-field").hasClass("field-error")) {
                $("#email-field").addClass('field-error');
            }
        } else {
            if ($("#email-field").hasClass("field-error")) {
                $("#email-field").removeClass('field-error');
            }
            if (!$("#email-field").hasClass("field-success")) {
                $("#email-field").addClass('field-success');
            }
        }
    });
}
```

```css
.login-frame .field-error { border-color: #A94442; }
.login-frame .field-success { border-color: #3C763D; }
```

Basically this function checks when an email field changes if its a valid email or not. If its not a valid email it removes the valid class if it exists and then adds the invalid class if it doesn't exist.

So my question is, this function seems over done to me. To many checks. Is there a more efficient way of doing the same thing?

Comment: Why do you need to check if it had a field before adding or removing it? Just do it without the checks. If the field is being removed and not there you won't get any error, and if you add it and it already exists, it doesn't get doubled. Also, read up on chaining.

Comment: I believe that `.change` is a bit overkill because it fires every keystroke. If you know that fact and want it then it's fine, but it suffice to use `.blur` instead for most of the cases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd simplify it with functions.
In abstract, it would be something like:

```
$('#email-field').blur(function () {
    var is_valid = is_valid($(this).val());
    if (is_valid){
        $("#email-field").addClass('field-success').removeClass('field-error');
    }else{
        $("#email-field").removeClass('field-success').addClass('field-error');
    }
});

function is_valid(email){
   //blah
}
```

Comment: That works very nicely. Thank you to everyone who answered. I appreciate the time!

Comment: glade I helped somebody today.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use `addClass` and `removeClass` without checking if the class already exists, since `addClass` will do nothing if the class is already there, and `removeClass` will do nothing if the class is not there.

Also, you can use method chaining to make the code shorter.

You can also assign `$('#email-field')` to a variable so jQuery doesn't have to search for the same element repeatedly.

```
var $emailField = $('#email-field');
if (!$emailField.val().match(emailCheck)) {
  $emailField.removeClass('field-success').addClass('field-error');
} else {
  $emailField.removeClass('field-error').addClass('field-success');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

https://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/

Refer to the toggleClass documentation

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the if statements using hasClass. JQuery will handle that logic for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#email-field').change(function () {
    var cl = ($(this).val().match(emailCheck)) ? 'field-success' : 'field-error';
    $(this).removeClass('field-success field-error').addClass(cl)
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
if ($(".register-frame").length) {
    var emailCheck = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/
    $('#email-field').change(function () {
        if (!$('#email-field').val().match(emailCheck)) {
            //since it is failure dont check 
                $("#email-field").removeClass('field-success'); //wont give error if not present
                $("#email-field").addClass('field-error');
            
        } else {
                $("#email-field").removeClass('field-error');
                $("#email-field").addClass('field-success');
        }
    });
}
```

```css
.login-frame .field-error { border-color: #A94442; }
.login-frame .field-success { border-color: #3C763D; }
```

or just simply you can do.

```
 $("#email-field").attr('class','new class') //new class can be either success or error
```